# "Number Only" Field with Comma Separators

Tags: javascript, php, numbers, keycode

I am working on creating a field that is basically number only besides having comma separators inserted at the thousand, million, etc. mark.

The first issue that In appear to be running into is whether or not keycode 188 even works for allowing commas.  When using the code here, I am unable to actually type a comma into the field, even though I appear to have excluded it from returning false:

```
function forceNumber(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
    if((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 58) && keyCode != 188)
        return false;
}
```

Here is the script that I am using to add the comma separators, I'm not entirely sure if it is this script, the one just referenced, or how I am calling them in the PHP file that is causing it not to function.  Here is the comma insertion js:

```
function numberWithCommas(n){
    n = n.replace(/,/g, "");
    var s=n.split('.')[1];
    (s) ? s="."+s : s="";
    n=n.split('.')[0]
    while(n.length>3){
        s=","+n.substr(n.length-3,3)+s;
        n=n.substr(0,n.length-3)
    }
    return n+s
}
```

And finally the PHP call:

```
<p>
            <label for="yearly_income"><?php _e('Yearly Income<br><i>Used to determine  fee per session</i>','mydomain') ?><br />
                <input type="number" name="yearly_income" id="yearly_income"     class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($yearly_income)); ?>" size="25"     onkeypress="return forceNumber(event);" onkeyup="this.value=numberWithCommas(this.value);"     /></label>
</p>
```

Any assistance on this would be wonderful.  It's amazing how complex it can be to get a field to work for something like inputting the income in a way that is user readable and friendly!

Comment: Are all your users using the same locale?

Comment: Isn't it 44 and not 188?

Comment: NEVER restrict what the user can type. Instead, wait for them to be done typing, then check if what they entered is valid and tell them if it is not.

Comment: Paulpro: should all be US users.  Kolink: Not sure why you would comment like this without an explanation.  Epascarello, when I checked it was 188.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `type="number"` to `type="text"`

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LAcj/)

The browser is interpreting `type="number"` and making sure you can't put anything but numbers in that field thats why it goes blank.

Comment: Thanks Abstract, works great in fiddle but it still doesn't work on the site, even after I changed the type to text.  https://jannus.org/wp-login.php?action=register.  I'm a bit baffled as to why.

Comment: The code that I altered in the original PHP was <input type="text" instead of <input type="number".  Otherwise it remained the same.

Comment: The HTML in the fiddle was not displaying correctly in Chrome...however when I changed it to '<input type="text" name="yearly_income" id="yearly_income" class="input" value="500" size="25" onkeypress="return forceNumber(event);" onkeyup="this.value=numberWithCommas(this.value);"/>' as suggested it still wasn't implementing the commas.  This is both in FF and Chrome.

Comment: I forgot to call the numbersWithCommas.js in the functions.php file after I created and uploaded it!  That would do it!  Added `function numberWithCommas() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'numberWithCommas', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/numberWithCommas.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'numberWithCommas' );` and it worked great.  Thank you!  AbstractChaos can sure give a concrete solution!